# Why do I get the error "Missing required arguments: personality, transport" when using Net::Appliance::Session?

Tags: perl

After playing dependency hell with a server that does not have internet access I finally was able to get a script running.  Problem is I get the following error and I have no idea how to find what is missing or wrong:

```
Missing required arguments: personality, transport at (eval 50) line 75.
```

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Appliance::Session;

my $s = Net::Appliance::Session->new( Host => '10.9.217.144', Transport => 'SSH', );
$s->connect( Name => 'cworks', Password => '****' );

print $s->cmd('show dialer | i :');
print "*********************\n**********************\n";
print $s->cmd('show ISDN stat | i ACTIV');
print "*********************\n**********************\n";
print $s->cmd('show ver');

$s->close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session), the [`new`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session#Net::Appliance::Session-new-options) method has two required arguments:

> **personality => $name (required)**
>
> Tells the module which "language" to use when talking to the connected device, for example ios for Cisco IOS devices. There's a list of all the supported platforms in the Phrasebook documentation. It's also possible to write new phrasebooks.
>
> **transport => $backend (required)**
>
> The name of the transport backend used for the session, which may be one of Telnet, SSH, or Serial.

You need to change `Transport` to `transport` and add a `personality` option, as in the example in the docs:

```
my $s = Net::Appliance::Session->new({
    personality => 'ios',
    transport => 'SSH',
    host => 'hostname.example',
});
```